# Why do I have to type ./ when executing scripts in my current directory?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is . not in the path by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)

This question might be trivial but I'm wondering why I have to type the dot and the slash before the name of my script in order to execute it, even though it is located in my current directory.

```
./my_script.sh
```

Whenever I type it without the dot & the slash:

```
my_script.sh
```

I just get **-bash: cloud_sync.sh: command not found**

What is the reason behind putting the **./** in front of a script name?

Thanks.

Comment: I am late to the party, but you can symlink (_ln -s /path/to/orig.sh /usr/bin/orig_) it to your /usr/bin folder from your scripts directory (/usr/bin is in your $PATH) and then you can just type my_script (it even tab-completes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have your current directory in your PATH, `export PATH=${PATH}:.`

Comment: Note that having your current directory in your path is considered a security risk. There is a good reason this is not the default on multi-user systems.

Comment: a better way would we to put user scripts to ~/bin and add this to your PATH variable.

Comment: I added current directory as the last path since it's somewhat safer then have it first. The best is of course to be explicit and have them in ~/bin.