# Kali Linux Requires Full Directory Path For All Command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, path, kali-linux

I'm having a problem on Kali Linux Lite 5.7.0 64-bit related to directory paths.
Not just the CD command, every command requires the full path.   For example, if I'm in a directory named "user/home/downloads/python3" and want to run the installer script, I can't just type in "bash installer.sh", If I do that it says "no such file or directory". I need to type in "bash user/home/downloads/python3/installer.sh" and then it runs. Also, it requires to do that not just for .sh files, but all files.
Thank You.
~1zuku

Comment: Related: [*Why is `.` not in the path by default?*](https://superuser.com/q/156582/432690)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is . not in the path by default?](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
bash ./installer.sh
```

to point the file in the current directory

Comment: Thanks! That's a life saver right there!