# SHELL="/bin/bash" vs SHELL="bash"

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables

What's the difference between exporting SHELL="/bin/bash" and SHELL="bash"? I previously had `export SHELL="bash"` in my .bashrc. It seemed to work. $($SHELL) spawned a subshell, but ssh with public key authentication gave the error: `Shell "bash" is not executable: No such file or directory`

Comment: `SHELL="bash` will only work if `bash` is in the current directory?

Comment: How does $(SHELL) spawn a subshell if bash isn't in the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `$($SHELL)` spawned a subshell

Yes, because in a shell `$SHELL` (or [better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) `"$SHELL"`) expands to `/bin/bash` or `bash` in your case, an both spawn Bash.

<sup>Side note: When you use `$($SHELL)`, the output coming from the new shell will be executed after the shell exits because this is how the command substitution (`$( … )`) works. Command substitution *makes little sense* here and it's not needed to show your point.</sup>

Your point seems to be: when `SHELL="bash"`, `"$SHELL"` runs Bash, yet some other tool (SSH server?) complains.

It's not clear what tool complains. And you did not tell us if `SHELL` is tampered with on the client side or on the server side. There is no [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367019/10765659) in the question. It's also not clear why you need to set `SHELL` in `.bashrc`. I'm not going to investigate any of these.

I'm going to tell you about `SHELL` and the difference between `/bin/bash` and `bash` *in general*.

The purpose of the `SHELL` environment variable is to point to the shell you want to use. Various software can use the variable (if set) to try to run your chosen shell for whatever reason. The difference you observed occurs because some programs rely on the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like), some don't.

The reliance on `PATH` works as follows. There's a string that "encodes" what executable to run. E.g. the string may be `/bin/bash`, `foo/bash` or `bash`. There are two cases:

1. If the string contains `/` then the string itself is interpreted as an absolute path (e.g. `/bin/bash`) or a relative path (e.g. `foo/bash`) to the executable.
2. If the string does not contain `/` (e.g. `bash`) then it only specifies the basename of the executable. The rest of the path (i.e. directory component(s)) comes from `PATH`. Basically it's the first directory specified in `PATH` that contains an executable with the specified basename. Depending on `PATH`, `bash` can be resolved as `/bin/bash`, `/home/you/bin/bash`, `./bash` ([rarely](https://superuser.com/q/156582/432690)) or not at all (giving you `command not found` or similar error).

Shells rely on `PATH`, therefore in a shell `bash` (typed literally or appearing from the expansion of `$SHELL` or whatever) finds `/bin/bash` or `/some/other/path/to/bash` in a sanely configured system.

Tools that don't rely on `PATH` treat the string as a path (pathname). This makes no difference for a string containing `/`. It makes a huge difference for a string not containing `/`. If the string is `bash` and it's interpreted directly as a path, it's equivalent to `./bash` which means "file named `bash` in the current working directory".

Whatever gave you the error apparently retrieved the content of the `SHELL` variable and used it as a path without relying on the `PATH` variable.

This was the right thing to do. Note POSIX [specifies `SHELL`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03) as:

> This variable shall represent a pathname of the user's preferred command language interpreter.

Investigate "[pathname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_271)" and "[pathname resolution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_13)", these do not rely on `PATH`. Any tool that uses the `SHELL` variable shall treat its content directly as a pathname.

When `SHELL="bash"`, in a shell `"$SHELL"` runs Bash only because `$SHELL` expands *like any other variable* and then `bash` is treated *like any other command not containing `/`*. So it's kinda incidental.

If I interpret the POSIX documentation right, you should use `SHELL="bash"` only if you mean `SHELL="./bash"`. Even if you mean this, it's better to use a path with `/`, so the mechanics in a shell where `PATH` can be used does not interfere with how `SHELL` shall be interpreted.

Most likely you don't want `./bash`. You want `/bin/bash` so use exactly this.