# Can not execute a file from terminal located in the same directory

Tags: macos, terminal.app

I want to execute `graldew`. It is definitely in the same directory and it has all the permission. But when I try to execute it I get `command not found`. Also I can not even autocomplete it using **TAB** button.

Could someone explain why is it happening?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `./graldew`?

`./` represents the current directory

Comment: Didn't explain why this is happening, though...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default

Answer (score 2):

> It is definitely in the same directory

Unlike Windows, the command-line shell in macOS (and other Unix-like systems) only executes commands found in $PATH and *doesn't* give any special treatment to "the same directory" – and the current directory **is not in $PATH** by default.

Files whose location isn't in $PATH can only be run using their exact path: `./gradlew` will work for files in the current directory (i.e. `.`), though full `/Users/..../android/gradlew` or `$PWD/gradlew` can be used too.

It is also possible to add `.` at the end of $PATH, though generally not recommended. (Adding it at the beginning, like in Windows, is very risky as downloaded files could override system commands such as 'ls' or 'rm'; having it at the end – a bit less so.)